# Form upper case input

Tags: html, forms, input, case

I have a form where users enter a surname. In case if they type it in all small case letters i want it to show up properly E.g. the user types in the word 'smith' but the response page will show 'Smith' instead?

```
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="surname"></p>
```

Comment: Please read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). In particular point 17. If someone tells you that their name is "smith" and not "Smith" then just believe them.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is capitalize your `input`, look snippet below:

P.S. - I edited your `p` class so you don't get confused when you apply the style to `input`. Because it could affect every `input` you may have in your site if was applied to `input` itself.

```css
.surname input {
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<p class="surname">Name:
  <input type="text" name="surname">
</p>
```

**EDIT:** here is jQuery solution, that will solve your problem with response page.

```js
   jQuery.fn.capitalize = function() {
        $(this[0]).keyup(function(event) {
            var box = event.target;
            var txt = $(this).val();
            var start = box.selectionStart;
            var end = box.selectionEnd;
            $(this).val(txt.replace(/^(.)|(\s|\-)(.)/g, function($1) {
                return $1.toUpperCase();
            }));
            box.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        });

       return this;
    }
    $('.surname input').capitalize();
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p class="surname">Name:
      <input type="text" name="surname">
    </p>
```

Comment: Just a quick note to anyone with limited CSS knowledge: this will alter the text of *any* input element. The user should use a more refined CSS selector when doing this.

Comment: That won't affect the data that gets sent to the response page, only the rendering of the input on the form page.

Comment: @Quentin I'm aware of that, But I'm pretty sure this is what OP wants and he was not be as cleared as possible in his question. OP already confirmed in above comment this is what he was looking for.

Comment: @dippas I just tested it and it doesn't seem to capitalize the name in the response.. i need to do that as well as it stores in a database.

Comment: @Quentin How would you do it?

Comment: @user666 — If I really wanted to screw about with the input, I'd do it on the server. I wouldn't want to do that though, see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the input value in the browser using Javascript and modify the value if the first character is not upper case. I'd recommend JQuery for that. Or use CSS to capitalize it.

Also note that browser-side Javascript or CSS transformations don't guarantee that a POST of your form will only send capitalized input; whatever happens in the browser can be bypassed. Hence, server-side you will want to do the same (capitalize if necessary).

Speaking of surnames, would you capitalize "van der Vaart"?

Comment: That last bit was also my question - we have a lot of "de la [something]" or "del [something]" where I live.

Comment: Yup, @Jhecht, agreed. So in that case I'd go with JQuery, and only capitalize if (a) the first character is NOT upper case, (b) there is NO space in the input followed by a capital. And of course the same processing server-side.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

text-transform: capitalize;

```
<p>Name: <input type="text" style="text-transform: capitalize;" name="surname"></p>
```

Comment: That won't affect the data that gets sent to the response page, only the rendering of the input on the form page.